# vertically populate cell values in a table using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to populate values vertically in column?

Lets say first column is list of service names. I have a form which fetch values for these service names as json. Now i want to show them in the table in second column.

```
     $scope.createReport =  function(report, query) {
        var vm = this;
        sampleservice.createReport(vm).then(
            function (data) {
                if(query ==  'ytod') {
                    $scope.ytod = data
                }else if(query ==  'month'){
                    $scope.month = data
                }else if(query ==  'year'){
                    $scope.year = data
                }
            }
        );
    };
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: updated.. please check

Comment: Show your html codes. And respective data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this and it works for me

```
               if(query ==  'month'){
                    var average = 0;
                    var count=0;
                    for (var key in data) {
                        var val = data[key];
                        if (val != 0) {
                            var insert = document.getElementById(key);
                            insert.deleteCell(1);
                            insert.insertCell(1).innerHTML = "<td>" + val + "</td>";
                            average += parseFloat(val);
                            ++count;
                        }
                    }

                }else if(query ==  'year'){
                    var average = 0;
                    var count=0;
                    for (var key in data) {
                        var val = data[key];
                        if (val != 0) {
                            var insert = document.getElementById(key);
                            insert.deleteCell(2);
                            insert.insertCell(2).innerHTML = "<td>" + val + "</td>";
                            average += parseFloat(val);
                            ++count;
                        }
                    }

                }
```